# object reference using mongoose

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var express = require("express");
var mongoose=require("mongoose");

// comment schema
var commentsSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  text:String
});

var comment=mongoose.model("text",commentsSchema);

// post schema
var postsSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  posts:String,
  texts:[
   {
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'text'
    }
]
});

var posts=mongoose.model("post",postsSchema);

// post route
app.get('/home',function(req,res){
  posts.find({},function(err,posts){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
  //    console.log(posts);
      res.render("index.ejs",{posts:posts});
    }
  });
});

// post route
app.post('/home',function(req,res){
  posts.create({posts:req.body.post,username:req.user.username},function(err,post){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("new post created");
      res.redirect("/home");
    }
  });
});

// comment route:- in this route i created comment pushed into post schema
app.post('/home/:id/comments',function(req,res){
  posts.findById(req.params.id,function(err,post){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var com=req.body.comment;
      var user=req.user.username;
      console.log(com);
      var com1={text:com,username:user};
      comment.create(com1,function(err,newComment){
        if(err){
          console.log("err");
        } else{
          console.log(newComment);
          post.texts.push(newComment);
          post.save();
          console.log(post);
          res.redirect("/home");
        }
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```html
   
<% posts.slice().reverse().forEach(function(post){ %>
    post.texts.forEach(function(comment){
      <%= comment.text %> // error:- showing object id instead of text
    });
<% }); %>
```

`<%= comment.text %>` ----- this html line is showing `objectId(ex:-5b5bf9afc21a414b54ab3290)` instead of comment on html page.Is post schema and comment schema are related correctly? if they are why i am getting `objectId` on html page instead of the comment in the database.

this is comment object in database

```
{ _id: 5b5bf9afc21a414b54ab3290,
  text: 'hey',
  username: 'yashwanth',
  __v: 0 }
```

this is post object in database which contains object reference of comment object

```
{ texts:
   [ { _id: 5b5bf9afc21a414b54ab3290,
       text: 'hey',
       username: 'yashwanth',
       __v: 0 } ],
  _id: 5b5bf9a9c21a414b54ab328f,
  posts: 'lol',
  username: 'yashwanth',
  __v: 0 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to populate child schema ( text)

Please go through this documentation

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population

```
posts.find({}).
  populate('texts').
  exec(function (err, posts) {...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using mongoose "ref" property then you have to use mongoose [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html) query with find query to populate post schema with comment schema. Give it a try this will definitely solve your problem.